# Azure Search Index Search Profile doesn't allow add functions

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

For some reason Azure Search Index Search Profile doesn't allow add functions.

Any ideas why?

Looks like I have required fields.

http://prntscr.com/6s9ldc

http://prntscr.com/6s9ljk

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While including the support for `Azure Search Service` in the product I was building, I encountered some undocumented business rules.

What I discovered is that **functions can only be defined on Filterable fields**. From the screenshot, it looks like the fields of type `Int32` & `DateTimeOffset` (required for `Magnitude` and `Freshness` type functions respctively) have only `Retrievable` property set in your index. They need to have `Filterable` property also set.

I have documented my findings here: http://gauravmantri.com/2014/09/17/azure-search-service-some-documentedundocumented-business-rules/ which you may find useful.

Since you can't update the fields, I think the only option for you is to drop the index and recreate it.

Comment: This particular business rule is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798928.aspx  It's not discoverable from the Portal error message though. We're looking at ways to improve error messages to make these rules clearer. Sorry for the inconvenience.